# WebClient.Downloadfile API is not working in powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

(new-object System.Net.WebClient).Downloadfile("https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tsyz48qg0rq3smz/QAstBLgPgN/version.txt", "C:\Users\Brangle\Desktop\version.txt") API download invalid data.

version.txt file need to download. But actually it is downloading some xml file contains in version.txt on destination location

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing it downloads exactly the same thing as I get when I go to that URI with my browser, which is an HTML document which presents, by my guess, the content of the version.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to download the dropbox page which *presents* your file in a nice dropbox-themed html. You need to extract the real url and can do so using the following code:

`` $wc = New-Object system.net.webclient;

$s = $wc.downloadString("https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tsyz48qg0rq3smz/QAstBLgPgN/version.txt");

$r = [regex]::matches($s,  "https://.*token_hash.*(?=`")");

$realURL = $r[$r.count-1].Value;

$wc.Downloadfile($realURL, "U:\version.txt"); ``

The regex part looks for a url starting https://, has a string token_hash in the middle and ends one character before double quotes character ". The line in question is:

FilePreview.init_text("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/sh/tsyz48qg0rq3smz/QAstBLgPgN/version.txt?token_hash=AAEGxMpsE-T4xodBPd3A6uPTCr0uqh7h4B2YUSmTDJHmjg", 0, null, 0)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It worked for me. URL was directing to dropbox-themed html. 
After giving download URL It is working fine.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to download file from logmein? Location is "https://secure.logmein.com/fileshare.asp?ticket=01_L5vwmOrmsS3mnxPO01f5FRbWUwVKlfheJ5HsfpTV"

Comment: I have "https://secure.logmein.com/f?01_NFlNXsRjZZWocCBclJfrB8EYIE9bak-j-40imC6u" logmein shared link.
It is giving me same themed html file after using above function. 
It worked nice for drop box but it is not working with logmein.

Comment: Here is my function
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

 $s = $wc.downloadString($source)
 $d = "/fileshare.asp.*ticket.*(?=`")"
 $r = [regex]::matches($s,$d)
 $realURL = $r[$r.count-2].Value
 $t = "https://secure.logmein.com"
 $t += $realURL
  
 if($wc.DownloadFile($t, $destination))
 {
   write-host "Error: not able to downlaod from $source to $destination"
   out-file -filepath $dailyStatusOpLog -append -inputobject "Error: not able to downlaod from $source to $destination" -encoding ASCII
   exit(1);
 }

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function:

```
function download-dropbox($Url, $FilePath) {
    $wc = New-Object system.net.webclient
    $req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Url)
    $req.CookieContainer  = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
    $res = $req.GetResponse()

    $cookies = $res.Cookies | % { $_.ToString()}
    $cookies = $cookies -join '; '

    $wc.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $cookies)
    $newurl = $url + '?dl=1'

    mkdir (Split-Path $FilePath) -force -ea 0 | out-null
    $wc.downloadFile($newurl, $tempFile)
}
```

Comment: I voted this up because it was written as a function.  But this could be improved if one would a) show the function being called so we can see the format of the Url, and b) show how one authenticates because presumably one needs to authenticate before downloading files.

Comment: I was using this function for public Dropbox downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Re: LogMeIn - theyuse a cookie base authentication so you can't use the previous code. Try this, it gets a cookie from the first response and then uses that to download using webclient:

```
$url = "https://secure.logmein.com/fileshare.asp?ticket=01_L5vwmOrmsS3mnxPO01f5FRbWUwVKlfheJ5HsfpTV"
$wc = New-Object system.net.webclient  
$req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)  
$req.CookieContainer  = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer  
$res = $req.GetResponse()
$cookie = $res.Cookies.Name + "=" + $res.Cookies.Value
$wc.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $cookie)  
$newurl = $url + "`&download=1"
$wc.downloadFile($newurl, "c:\temp\temp.zip")
```